# $('.selector').accordion(), what is this $('.selector') tag

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build an accordion using jQuery UI. I am following along with the documentation at https://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/ . The example requires a simple html file:

```
 <div id="accordion">
   <div >First header</div> <!-- header -->
   <div> <!-- content panel -->
     <p>First content panel</p>
     <p>some text</p>
   </div>
   <div>Second header</div> <!-- header -->
   <div>
     <p>Second content panel</p> <!-- content panel -->
     <p>more text</p>
   </div>
 </div>
```

And to activate the accordion:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
});
```

However, after getting the basic accordion working, every example afterwards uses this `$('.selector')` tag with no reference to where it came from. For example, to initialize the accordion with the 'active' option do this:

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion({
  active: 2
});
```

or to initialize the accordion with the 'animate' option do this:

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion({
  animate: 200
});
```

Where is this `$('.selector')` tag coming from? I have searched the html and do not see a `.selector` class and the examples using said tag are not working on my computer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `.selector` is just a placeholder for your selector.

Comment: @SebastianSimon this makes a lot of sense, thanks

Answer (score 1):

`$('.selector')` is the documentation's way of saying you can use a div with a css class as your accordion parent div

`.selector` = CSS class (if you've worked with CSS sheets you'll recognize the `.` syntax

Another example would be:

```
<div class="my-accordion">
  ... 
</div>
```

... which would be `$('.my-accordion').accordion()`

`$('#accordion')` would be a div with the id accordion, where `#` denotes an id